# Data structure for a set of changes similar to SVN?

Tags: mysql, sql, svn, data-structures

So far we have been storing information of changes as following.
Imagine having a changeset table structure of something that gets changed that is called object. The object is connected to say a foreign element by a foreign key. The object gets created like this

```
changesetId (Timestamp) | objectId | foreignKey | name (String) | description (String)
2015-04-29 23:28:52     | 2        |   123      |  none         | none
```

Now we change the name, the table will look like that after the name change

```
changesetId (Timestamp) | objectId | foreignKey | name (String) | description (String)
2015-04-29 23:28:52     | 2        |   123      |  none         | none
2015-04-29 23:30:01     | 2        |   null     |  foo          | null
```

This structure is exactly the minimum. It contains exactly the change we did. But to create the current version of the object, we have to add up the changes to actually get the final version. E.g.

```
    changesetId (Timestamp) | objectId | foreignKey | name (String) | description (String)
    2015-04-29 23:28:52     | 2        |   123      |  none         | none
    2015-04-29 23:30:01     | 2        |   null     |  foo          | null
   *2015-04-29 23:30:01     | 2        |   123      |  foo          | none
```

the * marking the final version, which does not exist in the DB.

So if we only store exactly the changes, we have more work to do. Especially, when coming from a foreign object `f`. If I have a number of objects `f` and I want to get all changes to the object from our table, I have to create a bit of an ugly SQL. This obviously gets worse, the more foreign objects you have.

Basically I have to do:

```
Select all F that I want and 
Select all objects WHERE foreignKey = foreignId
OR Select all objects that have objectId in (Select all objects that have foreignKey = foreignId)
```

e.g. I have to select the objects that have foreignKey 123 or elements that have foreignKey null but there exists an entry with same objectId with foreignKey 123.

The more dependencies, the uglier this SQL gets obviously.

Did I make myself clear?

Wouldn't it be much easier to keep always all fields in all versions

e.g. a simple name change gets:

```
changesetId (Timestamp) | objectId | foreignKey | name (String) | description (String)
2015-04-29 23:28:52     | 2        |   123      |  none         | none
2015-04-29 23:30:01     | 2        |   123      |  foo          | none
```

now to create a diff I have to compare both versions, but I don't have to do the extra work for selecting the right elements nor for calculating the final version of said timestamp.

What do you consider the proven best solution?
how is svn doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your use case the method you suggest seem to be better. Key value stores like LSM trees do exactly the same. They just write a newer version of the object without deleting the older version. If, at any point of time, you need the change that was made, I think you can just diff two adjacent versions.

The second method might use more space if you have a lot of variable length text fields, but that's a trade-off you get for speed and maintainability.